# Install module/package from download files

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to install a module (scikits.audiolab)
I have tried to do this from terminal however I did not succeed.
I have downloaded the files from https://pypi.org/project/scikits.audiolab/#files

How do I install the package from these download files?
Thanks

Comment: What does _I did not succeed_ mean, exactly? Why are you trying to install it like this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

to install that package simply open your terminal/cmd and type

```
pip install scikits.audiolab
```

Answer (score 0):

if `pip install scikits.audiolab` is not working...you should be able to:

navigate to the package folder and run

```
python setup.py install
```